# dd a partition pipe it to gzip and pipe that to an aws bucket

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, gzip, dd

I've been trying to tweak the following one-liner to get it to `dd` a partition, `gzip` it and copy it to an s3 bucket. However after countless tries it still does nothing

```
sudo dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap-00 | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://backup-bucket/backup.gz
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `pv` (*pipe viewer*) is a handy tool to see the progress in the pipe. Install it and use it like this: `sudo dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap-00 | pv | gzip | pv |aws s3 cp - s3://backup-bucket/backup.gz`

Comment: awesome tool! thanks. I'm trying it out.

Comment: I think the problem may be on the `gzip` command since you are writing the compressed output on the `stdout` (and for that purpose you need to add the flags `gzip -fc`). However, I don't know if the following `aws` command expects a compressed stdin or a filename.

Comment: aws can take any kind of stream @hek2mgl, using pv I've found that dd tries to take a block copy of my entire disk (225G) instead of the used (362M), leading to a no space left on disk error, I've also found that my aws cp command fails on CreateMultiPartUpload, that's probably not enabled. My problem now seems to be the size of the snapshot created is the size of the whole partition and not the size I pass to lvcreate 362M, which is weird but explains all this. I've opened a new question on unix stackexchange for that.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387818/lvcreate-snapshot-creates-a-larger-snapshot-than-the-snapshot-size

Answer (score 0):

use the -c flag with gzip

From man page:

```
-c --stdout --to-stdout
Write output on standard output; keep original files unchanged.  If there are several input files, the output consists of a sequence of independently compressed members. To obtain better compression, concatenate all input files before compressing them.
```

Then,

```
sudo dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap-00 | gzip -c | aws s3 cp - s3://backup-bucket/backup.img.gz
```

Thanks